# Windows volume get size, free space

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I need to get total space and used space of a SAN volume in Windows. There are too many volumes on the server to mount using the Windows letter mount points. Instead the server software mounts all available volumes in C:\Volumes path.

```
wmic logicaldisk get volumename, size, freespace
```

is fast and works great, but it only lists the volumes mounted as Windows letters.

```
dir \s \a C:\Volumes\SomeVolumeName
```

returns the information I need, but it's very slow as it recurses through all the files. I have hundreds of thousands of files on each volume.

```
du C:\Volumes\SomeVolumeName
```

is slow for the same reason as the dir command.

Is there any other way to get fast stats on a volume from the Windows command line or even better from Python?

Comment: This should give you all volumes: `wmic volume get Capacity, FreeSpace, Label, Name`.

Comment: wmic works only with volumes that have a letter assigned. That doesn't work in my case. I have more volumes than the letters in the alphabet.

Comment: It's using `volume`, not `logicaldisk`. It worked for me on a disk mounted in a folder without a drive letter. I wouldn't have suggested it otherwise. The `Name` field should be the folder where the volume is mounted.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "volume" argument in your comment. It's odd. It lists some of the volumes but not all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `psutil`

> psutil (python system and process utilities) is a cross-platform
>   library for retrieving information on running processes and system
>   utilization (CPU, memory, disks, network) in Python. It is useful
>   mainly for system monitoring, profiling and limiting process resources
>   and management of running processes. It implements many
>   functionalities offered by command line tools such as: ps, top, lsof,
>   netstat, ifconfig, who, df, kill, free, nice, ionice, iostat, iotop,
>   uptime, pidof, tty, taskset, pmap. It currently supports Linux,
>   Windows, OSX, Sun Solaris, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and NetBSD, both 32-bit
>   and 64-bit architectures, with Python versions from 2.6 to 3.5 (users
>   of Python 2.4 and 2.5 may use 2.1.3 version). PyPy is also known to
>   work.

https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/

And for you, particulary this part of the documentation : https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#disks

Comment: As noted in the docs, if you're using Python 3, then you can use [`shutil.disk_usage`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage). This works with volume mountpoints on Windows.

Comment: `psutil.disk_partitions` only lists volumes that have a DOS drive letter. That's disappointing.

Comment: @eryksun you tried with `psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)` ?

Comment: I think this will work perfectly in my script: psutil.disk_usage(someVolumePath). It's very fast too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in the [source](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/release-5.0.0/psutil/_psutil_windows.c#L2434) you can see that it only iterates over "logical" drives (i.e. volumes mounted with a DOS drive letter) and that `all=True` means to include all drive types.

Comment: If they wanted to expand this to all volumes, they could iterate using [`FindFirstVolume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364425). To list all mount points for a volume, call [`GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364998). Or iterate over all mount points for a volume path via [`FindFirstVolumeMountPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364426).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the requried data from the below script. Enter all the volumes in your system in the array $DriveLetter and  it doesn't take much time to execute

```
$DriveLetter="C,D"
$DriveLetters=$DriveLetter.Split(',')
foreach ($item in $DriveLetters)
{
$data=Get-PSDrive $item | Select-Object Used,Free
$UsedData=$data.Used
$FreeSPace=$data.Free
"Used Space in Drive $item : $UsedData"
"Free space in Drive $item : $FreeSPace"
}
```

Hope it HElps.

Comment: The volumes are mounted in subdirectories of `C:\Volumes`. They are not assigned DOS drive letters.

Comment: PowerShell has [`Get-Volume`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848646), e.g. `foreach ($v in Get-Volume -FilePath C:\Volumes) {Write-Output ("Name: {0}\`nSize: {1}\`nFree: {2}\`n" -f ($v.FileSystemLabel, $v.Size, $v.SizeRemaining))}`.

Comment: My PS does not have Get-Volume. There is Get-WMIObject though, but it doesn't see all my volumes, kind of like wmic discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

in this .bat script you can catch the volume free space in GB and compare it, you can to catch the total volume. 
try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2,3,4" %%a in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart') do (
::echo o volume %%b
::fsutil volume diskfree %%b:
set result=E
set size=0
set free=0
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %%b:') DO (
::echo Dtotal "%%i"
    if "%%i" == "Total free bytes        " ( 
        FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=(" %%m in ('echo %%j') do (
            ::echo splittotal %%i : %%n
            FOR /f "tokens=1delims=," %%k in ('echo %%n') do (
                ::echo splittotalGB %%i :%%k
                set free=%%k
            )
        )
        set result=A
    )
    if "%%i" == "Total bytes             " (
        FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=(" %%m in ('echo %%j') do (
            ::echo splittotal %%i : %%n
            FOR /f "tokens=1delims=," %%k in ('echo %%n') do (
                ::echo splittotalGB %%i :%%k
                set size=%%k
            )
        )
    )
)
if "!result!" == "A" (
    echo result !size!x!free!
    set /a nfree=!free!*1
    set /a min=40
    if !free! lss !min! (
        echo ok
        set MSG=The partition %%b on server_complete_name have only !free! from total !size!
    )
)
)
```